# Not found error for ajax in ASP.NET MVC release configuration

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on an ASP.NET MVC site and I am having trouble with ajax posts in my release build. The site has two database connections, one to a "dummy" server that allows me to test code without affecting the live server. So, I had to configure the site to point to the live server for the release configuration, and the dummy server for the debug configuration.

Everything other than the database connection is the same, but for some reason my ajax call works fine on the debug build but throws an error on the release build. I get an ERROR THROWN: Not found alert on the ajax failure, but it only fails in the release build.

My call to the controller method looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@Url.Action("ReleasePlotFieldName", "TestRecord")" + '?fieldName=' + x + '&fileName=' + filename,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");

            for (var key in data) {
                let b = {
                    name: data[key][0],
                    value: data[key][1],
                    line: data[key][2],
                    arc: data[key][3]
                };

                chartData.push(b);
            }

            PlotData();
            //the parameter data contains the array returned from the json PlotFieldName function
        },
          error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('STATUS: ' + textStatus + '\nERROR THROWN: ' + errorThrown);
        }
```

and the controller method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ReleasePlotFieldName(string fieldName, string fileName)
{
    var spiData = (DataDecoder)Session["dataDecode"];

    var selectedItem = fieldName;
    spiData.DecodeData(selectedItem);
       
    List<float[]> toPlot = spiData.returnPlotVector();
        
    return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = toPlot,
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue // Use this value to set your maximum size for all of your Requests    
        };
}
```

I have absolutely no clue why the release build is not executing as expected (as the debug build is doing). I welcome any and all suggestions.

Here is the network tab of the browser when the call is made
[image]

Comment: When it says NOT FOUND is that a 404 or what? The network tab of the browser should have more information on what your request and response looks like. Making sure that ‘x’ and ‘file name’ variables are forming a valid url would be my first start

Comment: I added a screenshot of the network tab when the error occurs.

Comment: From your code I expect the ajax call will contains `?fieldName=xxx&fileName=yyy` but  the screenshot does not have those params. Are you sure the app you are running is using the code you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller action is decorated with a `[HttpPost]` attribute but your jquery `.ajax()` request is a `GET`. Change one or the other depending on your use case (looks like GET could be more appropriate).